# Jetpack Compose: Fixing one element to another

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I have a default `Card` element with some things in it and a `LazyColumn`. So, is it possible to fix somehow a `LazyColumn` to the bottom of the card (that is not about StickyHeader)?
Basically, I want this Card not to hover above the LazyColumn.

[image]

Comment: Can help to add a mock? hopefully can help to better describe your expectation

Comment: sorry, forgot about that, added a small sketch, representing my question

Comment: "Basically I want this Card not to hover above the LazyColumn" - Why not a Row/Card then a LazyColumn at the same view heirarchy level?  Sorry not used Compose but its just rows and column right like a flexible staggered grid system?

Comment: Why not just use a `Column`?

Comment: Because LazyColumn is recommended to use when you have a `List`, I suppose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them both in a `Column`:

```kotlin
Column {
    Card {
        // ...
    }
    LazyColumn(...) {
       // ...
    }
}
```